# How to write a module with variable number of ports in Verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I would like to write a module with a variable number of inputs, i.e. depending on some parameter, the result would be:

```
module my_module #(LENGTH)(
    input clk,
    input rst_n,
    input [LENGTH-1:0] data_1
);
//...
endmodule
```

or

```
module my_module #(LENGTH)(
    input clk,
    input rst_n,
    input [LENGTH-1:0] data_1,
    input [LENGTH-1:0] data_2,
    input [LENGTH-1:0] data_3
);
//...
endmodule
```

Would it be possible to do this in Verilog or Systemverilog or would I have to write a script, let's say in Python, in order to generate the code for a specific module with fixed number of inputs? (it might be more than 1000 inputs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no variable number of ports in SystemVerilog, but you could use a port that is a parameterized array.

```
module my_module #(int LENGTH, DEPTH)(
    input clk,
    input rst_n,
    input [LENGTH-1:0] data[DEPTH]
);
//...
endmodule
```

Otherwise, you would need to use a script to generate the code.

Comment: Thats what I thought. just another question, wouldnt it be input [LENGTH-1:0] data[0:DEPTH-1] ?

Comment: In SystemVerilog your can specify the dimension of an array (unpacked array dimension ) as [DEPTH] instead of [0:DEPTH-1]. This matches C/C++ array notation. You can't do that with the LENGTH (packed array dimension) however.

Answer (score 3):

Use a two dimensional input with a parameterized size. Added a *generate for loop* that can be used to set signals individually. Although many operations can be done with smart array operations.

```
module my_module #(SIZE, LENGTH)(
    input clk,
    input rst_n, 
    input [SIZE-1:0][LENGTH-1:0] data_in_array,
    output [SIZE-1:0][LENGTH-1:0] data_out_array
);
genvar N;
generate for (N=0; N<SIZE; N++) begin :la_coolOps
    //Do cool operations here. For example instantiate a module for every data_in
end
//...
endmodule
```

Edit:
As Mehran Torki points out: The syntax above will work for SystemVerilog only. Verilog does not allow for multiple packed arrays. Use `input [LENGTH*SIZE-1:0] data_in_array`.

Comment: Please mention that this code won't work in verilog, giving this error in ModelSim: `Multiple packed dimensions are not allowed.` In verilog, one dimensional input must be used, with length equal to `(SIZE*LENGTH)-1`.

Answer (score 1):

As others said, there is no direct way to do this, but another workaround is to use SystemVerilog interfaces, where you define all the inputs that you want in the interface definition and inside the module only use the ones that correspond to the parameter. Below is a sample:

```
module my_module #(LENGTH)(
       input clk;
       input rst_n;
       output o;
       interface i_data;
    );
    logic outValue;

    generate
        case (LENGTH) //Based on the value of LENGTH, use corresponding data
            1: outValue = i_data.data_1;
            2: outValue = i_data.data_1 + i_data.data_2;
            3: outValue = i_data.data_1 + i_data.data_2 + i_data.data_3;
        endcase 
    endgenerate

    always @(posedge clk) begin
    if (~rst_n)
        o <= '0;
    else
    begin
        o <= outValue;
    end

endmodule
```

You can still use a parameterized array for data and a for-generate loop if your outputs are similar.

Comment: This is a cool approach to know, but unfortunately does not solve the problem of having a variable number of inputs. Anyway, thanks for sharing this with us :)

Comment: Is it possible to make signals inside the interface optional? I.e. not create them if some parameter is set to a certain value?

Answer (score 1):

I would add to these other answers that ports are just groupings of wires. While having 3, 1-bit wires named a, b, and c might be easier to read and understand, there is no physical/logical difference between a single, 3-bit wire `abc`, where `abc[0]` corresponds to `a`, `abc[1]` corresponds to `b`, and `abc[2]` corresponds to `c`.

So, you can always just expand or shrink a single (or multiple) signal(s) to get however many bits you need. It may not be as neat, but it will work. In the receiving module, you can then part-select the bus in whatever manner you like. So, you could have one really long wire the shrinks or expands (`wire [(SOME_PARAM*8)-1:0] my_input_wire`), or with SystemVerilog an array (`wire [7:0] my_input_wire[0:SOME_PARAM-1]`)

If this is just testbench/verification code, the other thing you could do in SystemVerilog is use a dynamic array

Comment: Actually, I was just avoiding to do this way because it would not be nice to debug after. But sure, you are right, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

With System verilog we can import a package instead of having parameterization and define types in the package to be used in the portlist.

```
module mymodule
  import mymodule_pkg::*;
(
    input portlist_t portlist
);
endmodule
```

And define multiple copies of the package with different variants of the port list and compile whichever version is required. eg

```
package mymodule_pkg;

   localparam LENGTH=5;

   typedef struct packed {
      logic [LENGTH-1:0] data_1,
      logic [LENGTH-1:0] data_2,
      logic [LENGTH-1:0] data_3
   } portlist_t;

endpackage
```

As with the interface solution there will be situations where you run into issues, like having different iterations of the module instantiated together.