# Variable size and number of port/array port in module which are parameter dependent in Verilog System verilog

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

Reference to the below asked question

[How to write a module with variable number of ports in Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35156150/how-to-write-a-module-with-variable-number-of-ports-in-verilog/45098462)

I Have another question on this.

```
module my_module #(SIZEOF_LENGTH = 3,
                    LENGTH = {8,8,7})(
    input clk,
    input rst_n,
    input [LENGTH[0]-1:0] data_1,
    input [LENGTH[1]-1:0] data_2,
    input [LENGTH[2]-1:0] data_3
);
```

I basically want something like this. Size is dependent on the parameter passed from top and so is the number of ports. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Not in Verilog, but could use a templating language like Ruby or Perl.

Alternatively in SystemVerilog Array ports can be used: 
Note these have to be the same Width.

```
module my_module #(
    SIZEOF_LENGTH = 3,
    LENGTH = 8)(
    input clk,
    input rst_n,
    input [LENGTH-1:0] data [0:SIZEOF_LENGTH-1]
);
```

Comment: this shorthand notation will work as well

 `input [LENGTH-1:0] data[SIZEOF_LENGTH]`

Comment: Thats the issue, I want a variable lenght on the data part. It should be possible since its a HDL but the LRM doesnt support i guess.